# How to automatically shutdown laptop if unplugged

Tags: windows-7, windows, power-management

I want my laptop to shutdown automatically after it gets disconnected from power. Can someone tell me if there exists some app for this for Windows 7

Comment: If you remove the battery it will automatically shut down (in a sense) when you remove power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Type “Power Options” in Start Menu search text field and hit enter key.
> 2. Click on “Change Plan Settings” in front of active plan (Balanced, High Performance or Power Saver).
> 3. Click on “Change advanced power settings”.
> 4. In the next window scroll down and find the “Battery” option, Expand it.
> 5. Expand “Low battery Level” and change the “on battery” value a high value e.g 95%.
> 6. Expand the “Low battery action” and change the “on battery” option to Shutdown.

[Source](http://www.trickyways.com/2010/07/how-to-automatically-shutdown-laptop-if-unplugged/)

Comment: Links can potentially die. Please provide also the following steps in your answer, so that the solution will still be available even if the given site is not answering.

Comment: Smart, should have thought of it.
Steps are: 
0. Go to power plan settings in Windows 7.
1. Set your low battery level to very high, say 95%.
2. Set your low battery action to shutdown/hibernate. 
Done.

Answer (score 0):

> For those of you having the problem of a HP laptop shutting off when you unplug the charger and your battery is fully charged, I can help you. There is nothing wrong with the laptop, battery, or computer, it is a power management setting. If you go to display properties, select the screen saver tab, then click the "power" button, in the power schemes field is a drop down window, click on it and select "Rixane Power Scheme", it is a power switching utility that quickly switches between AC and Battery when the power cable/charger is plugged in or unplugged while the laptop is on. If you have it set to "always on" it will shut off when you pull the power cord, even if the battery is charged. This will also happen on many non-HP laptops, if you don't have a HP laptop or there is not a "Rixane" option available, select the "Portable/Laptop" power scheme. Hope this helps!

Source: [Click Here](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-198127-laptop-turns-of-when-power-cord-is-removed)